# How to order the results from ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock

Tags: objective-c, alassetslibrary

**Question**

I want to order the results returned from my `ALAssetsLibrary` in way which `Camera Roll` will be on top of my array.

**Code**

This is my enumeration block which walk through all returned items.

```
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if(group) {
        [_groups addObject:group];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really only care that camera roll is first, you could build up the array where you insert the camera roll at the beginning and append all other groups, like this:

```
groups = [NSMutableArray new];
ALAssetsLibraryGroupsEnumerationResultsBlock listGroupBlock = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    if (group) {
        if ([group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupType]== ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos]) {
            [groups insertObject:group atIndex:0];
        }
        else {
            [groups addObject:group];
        }
    }
    else {
        // group is nil, so there are no more groups to enumerate
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
};
```

This way you don't have to write any additional sorting code, everything will just be in the right place.  As Robert notes, there's no reason to reload with every iteration.

Comment: I've replaced `[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupType]` with `[[group valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyType] intValue]`

Answer (score 0):

In your block, do this ...

```
if ( group ) {
  [_groups addObject:group];
} else {
  // Sort your groups in _groups here
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

... according to the documentation, iteration ends when `group` is `nil`. In this way you can fetch all groups, sort them and then reload table view. It has no sense to reload it after each group you do receive - it's fast process in this case.